# Populating Country column from international phone numbers

Tags: python, pandas, python-phonenumber

I have a dataframe with several data including the column `phone`.
I would like to create a column name `country`, based on the phone numbers.
The phone numbers are in the format +country_code_phonenumber, i.e.,for several countries.
Example

```
+351xxxxxxxxx
+1xxxxxxxxxx
+34xxxxxxxxx
+55xxxxxxxxxxx
```

What is the best way to do this with the library [phonenumbers](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/)? Or is there another way to do it that I'm missing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best way, but I was not able to find the way without looping...

```
import pandas as pd
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder, carrier


df = pd.DataFrame(['+41431234567', '+447399512658'], columns=['Number'])

ph_numbers = df['Number'].values # creating list of numbers

country_list = []  # empty list for countries
for item in ph_numbers:
    numb = phonenumbers.parse(item, 'en') # creating phonenumber object
    print(geocoder.description_for_number(numb, 'en'))
    country_list.append(geocoder.country_name_for_number(numb, 'en')) #passing phonenumber object to geocoder and appending to list

df['Country'] = country_list
```

Comment: this works in general, and that's why I accepted the answer. However it returns a mix of countries and cities, which is weird I have to say

Comment: my apologies, I have updated the code, `country_name_for_number` should be used instead of `.description_for_valid_number`